# Putting Core-Plot Objects into xcode 4.3.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks, core-plot

I am trying to follow this tutorial ([Using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application)).  When I try to drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file from the core-plot/framework directory into my project, I don't have anything appear that allows me to put the library into my xcode project. Is it my version compared to the tutorials verison?  Can anyone tell me how I would do this with a version of xcode 4.3.3?  Thanks

Comment: Rather than following that older tutorial, I'd recommend using the up-to-date installation instructions on the Core Plot wiki: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications . Of course, I wrote those, so I'm a little biased. I do know they work with the latest version of Xcode, because I've used them recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the instructions at the beginning of this tutorial, its what worked for me and I just set up CorePlot last week.

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/

Additionally you don't want to drag the .xcodeproj file, there are a different set of files that you want that are noted at the beginning of the above tutorial.

Comment: Hey Karoly S, I am just getting the chance to try out the tutorial.  So far I am at the part where I'm trying to add "-ObjC -all_load" to the "Other Linker Flags" settings. I don't know what to click to add the settings.  When I click "Add Build Setting" it only gives me the option to "Add User-Defined Setting". Need some help.

Comment: @user1496143 Sure thing! It sounds like you are in the right place, all you need to do is double click that "Other Linker Flags" entry area and it should pop out a dialog box. This box will have a "+" and "-" symbol on the bottom left, press the plus symbol and it will give you a chance to add a flag. The order doesn't matter, just make sure you add both "-ObjC" and "-all_load" Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file to your project

Go to the Build Phases section of the settings for your current target.

Expand the target Dependencies section, hit the + button and there should be an option for CorePlot-CocoaTouch, add it.

Expand the Link Binary With Library Section, hit +, choose libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a

Go to build settings, and under header search paths add the appropriate path, I use "${PROJECT_DIR}/../core-plot/Source/framework"

got to other linker flags and add -ObjC

The next 2 instructions are not required for getting your app to build, but are needed to get it to build an archive for the App Store.

Now go to the filebrowser for your project, choose the core-plot project, choose the CorePlot-CococaTouch target, in the settings search for Skip Install and set it to yes

Go to Build Phases, expand the Copy Headers section, move all of the headers to the project section.

Comment: You say to drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file to my project.  Where exactly do i drag that?

Comment: Where exactly do you put the header search path?   And do I type exactly that?